# How to make interface if key is dynamic value?

Tags: typescript

I am working with ShazamCore Api.I need to get artist details but object key is artist id, which i take from query paramets.I use nextjs and typescript.
Code:

```
export interface IArtist{
  artists: {
     [dynamic key] : value
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you use the interface for? I would expect the IDs to just be strings, so I probably would just use a `Map<string, IArtistData>` (where `IArtistData` is the type you would put as value in your code)

Comment: what is the type of artist id ?   If it is a string ```artists: Record<string, TypeOfArtistDetails>```

Comment: Thank you ! How can i get value in my code - like song.artists.dynamicValue.atttributes.name ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
export interface IArtist{
    artists: {
        [key: number] : {}
    }
}
```